# Enable "Allow remote connections to this server" SQL Server Option via the Registry

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, registry

I would like to put together a PowerShell script that will automatically enable the "Allow remote connections to this server" option for SQL Server. I was thinking a registry update would do the trick. Does anyone know where in the registry this update can be made?

This is the option I would like to enable in the back end:
[image]

If there is a different/easier way to enable this option using PowerShell that does not involve a registry update, I would be up for those suggestions as well. Thanks in advance!

**Note:** I don't know if this makes a difference, but I'm reviewing this on SQL Server 2019.

Comment: what registry entry are you talking avout that us a simpole option if the server, besides you need to enable tcpip and sqlbrowser has to be startet

Comment: I think you can do that through regular t-sql: [Configure remote access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure). I would think you could wrap something like that in an `Invoke-SqlCmd`

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to put together a PowerShell script that will automatically enable the "Allow remote connections to this server" option for SQL Server.

That setting doesn't do what you think it does, and should be ignored.  This setting is only relevant for the deprecated [Remote Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/remote-servers?view=sql-server-ver16) feature, and is unrelated to client connectivity.  See eg: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146883/sql-server-allow-remote-connections-to-this-server-option-what-does-this-do

Its presence in so many non-official troubleshooting guides is a mistake.

So follow the docs here: [Enable or disable a server network protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver16)